# Signature in ruby to php

Tags: php, ruby, laravel, api, typeform

I have create api to recive data of Typeform(surveys https://www.typeform.com/). It works fine.
But, in secure webhooks, https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/secure-your-webhooks/, shows example of how create signature in ruby, to compare in request.

In laravel i use this:

```php
$body = $req->getContent();
$sig_internal = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', 'testing', $body, true));
```

My "secret" configured in webhooks of the typeform is "testing".
But the values is different always.
Somebody have try this?

Comment: It's a little hard to work out exactly what you're asking - is it that the example given, in Ruby, generates a different signature to Laravel/PHP?

Comment: Have you tried to compare the two contents without hashing them?  Maybe there are invisible characters.

Comment: @CD001 in the site of typeform have an example to create a "signature" to compare in request. That example is in ruby, and i wrote in php. The code is right?
My problem is, in POST request send from typeform to api, the header in request "typerform-signature" is always different.

Comment: @Alex83690 the typeform-signature coming in header of request, and it was already encoded. I need generate the signature to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running the code make sure that you set your secret properly with Typeform: 
[How to set up your webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swVb3.png)

More info here: 
https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/secure-your-webhooks/

Once that's done let's jump into the code. I paste here what you need to do step by step:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class WebhookController extends Controller
  {
     public function index(Request $request){

     // Get your data (toString) and the typeform signature
     $data = (string) $request->getContent();
     $typeformSignature = $request->header('typeform-signature');        

     // Set your key 
     $key = 'test'; // <-- In prod I recommend adding it to the .env file and referring it here 

     // Run your hash
     $hashed = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key, $raw_output = TRUE);

     // Encode to Base64
     $base64 = base64_encode($hashed);

     // Append to string
     $endValue = "sha256=". $base64;

     // This bit here will output stuff to your console if you are running artisan
     error_log($endValue);
     error_log($request->header('typeform-signature'));

     // If it's good it should praise the good Bro, otherwise you are a bad bro. :) 
     if($request->header('typeform-signature') === $endValue){
        error_log('Well done bro!');
     } else {
        error_log('Sorry bro!');
     }        
    }  
  }
```

Comment: this is payload: https://paste.debian.net/1081749/ and this is typeform-signature: http://images.devs-on.net/Image/8OsxSPVwyQgzK0GD-Region.png

When we generate this way you wrote and i too, alway signature is different
http://images.devs-on.net/Image/Ek76OmKQttKhqcBE-Region.png.

Comment: The code: https://paste.debian.net/1081751/

Comment: are you copy pasting the JSON in postman? If so, note that this won't work. I would recommend using something like Ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) and configuring a test webhook in Typeform so you can test with the original request from Typeform.

Comment: Why postman doesn't work? I Will try your recomendation anyway.

Comment: The format you copy / paste from the website has spaces, breaklines and so on... The original request turned into a string doesn't.

Also, make sure you turned it to string
     $data = (string) $request->getContent();

In your code I can see that you don't do that.

Comment: doesnt work. Here is my function https://paste.debian.net/1081886/. This is request (http://images.devs-on.net/Image/y9aMag37fIUnyRxA-Region.png) and this is response (http://images.devs-on.net/Image/1GHgD0ZAV2kTcDym-Region.png).

Comment: I tested the solution again and it works. You might want to raise a ticket with our support team at support@typeform.com. Direct it to me (Nordin) and I'll help you out there.

Comment: I sent the email today, requesting the forwarding of the ticket to you.